# pinch to zoom don't center zoom

Tags: android, xamarin, zooming, android-canvas

Im trying to do a pinch to zoom on a imageview. The problem is that the when i zoom it does'nt scale where i pinched it scales up to the left corner. Im not sure why i does this and i seems that there is a lot of people having the same problem but i havent found a soloution to it yet.

```
  public override bool OnTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)
   {
    _scaleDetector.OnTouchEvent(ev);

MotionEventActions action = ev.Action & MotionEventActions.Mask;
int pointerIndex;

switch (action)
{
    case MotionEventActions.Down:
    _lastTouchX = ev.GetX();
    _lastTouchY = ev.GetY();
    _activePointerId = ev.GetPointerId(0);
    break;

    case MotionEventActions.Move:
    pointerIndex = ev.FindPointerIndex(_activePointerId);
    float x = ev.GetX(pointerIndex);
    float y = ev.GetY(pointerIndex);
    if (!_scaleDetector.IsInProgress)
    {
        // Only move the ScaleGestureDetector isn't already processing a gesture.
        float deltaX = x - _lastTouchX;
        float deltaY = y - _lastTouchY;
        _posX += deltaX;
        _posY += deltaY;
        Invalidate();
    }

    _lastTouchX = x;
    _lastTouchY = y;
    break;

    case MotionEventActions.Up:
    case MotionEventActions.Cancel:
    // We no longer need to keep track of the active pointer.
    _activePointerId = InvalidPointerId;
    break;

    case MotionEventActions.PointerUp:
    // check to make sure that the pointer that went up is for the gesture we're tracking. 
    pointerIndex = (int) (ev.Action & MotionEventActions.PointerIndexMask) >> (int) MotionEventActions.PointerIndexShift;
    int pointerId = ev.GetPointerId(pointerIndex);
    if (pointerId == _activePointerId)
    {
        // This was our active pointer going up. Choose a new
        // action pointer and adjust accordingly
        int newPointerIndex = pointerIndex == 0 ? 1 : 0;
        _lastTouchX = ev.GetX(newPointerIndex);
        _lastTouchY = ev.GetY(newPointerIndex);
        _activePointerId = ev.GetPointerId(newPointerIndex);
    }
    break;

}
return true;
```

}

```
  protected override void OnDraw(Canvas canvas)
 {
base.OnDraw(canvas);
canvas.Save();
canvas.Translate(_posX, _posY);
canvas.Scale(_scaleFactor, _scaleFactor, _lastTouchX, _lastTouchY);
_icon.Draw(canvas);
canvas.Restore();
}
```

I think  it might have to do with this code in the beginning of the class where the bounds of the image is set to 0. But if i delete that code the image wont render.

```
public GestureRecognizer(Context context, ImageView imgview)
        : base(context, null, 0)
    {
        //_icon = context.Resources.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.ic_launcher);
        _icon = imgview.Drawable;
        _icon.SetBounds(0, 0, _icon.IntrinsicWidth, _icon.IntrinsicHeight);
        _scaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new MyScaleListener(this));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at MultiTouchController library. It makes it much easier to write multitouch applications for Android and pinch to zoom, rotate and drag is nicely implemented. Here is the [link](https://code.google.com/p/android-multitouch-controller/).

Comment: although that seems like a nice thing to try it seems they have the same problem with their library:
"KNOWN BUGS: For pinch-zoom, currently the center of the scaling operation is the center of the pinched object, not the midpoint between the two touch points on the screen, due to an error in converting between screen and object coordinates and vice versa. This needs to be fixed, and would be a nice (and relatively simple) contribution if anyone is willing to submit a patch :-) It requires some understanding of composition of transformations. "